# Angular 2 http request: how to set Authorization with username, password and domain

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an API method hosted from another machine and I can connect to it when using it on the browser with typing user name and password like below:

[image]

But I don't know how to call that method on the Angular 2 component with Http.

Here is my code:

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('myUsername:myPassword'));
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });
    return this.http.get(urlParam, requestOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => JSON.parse(response.json()))
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Here is the error I got:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.103:44411/api/Profile/user/1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:6823' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a server-side problem.
You have to set those headers:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
```

on your server!